# "Discovered - currently not indexed" in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have a 25 page website that I have submitted the sitemap for, but I have 13 pages that are under "Discovered - currently not indexed". I have clicked on `Validate Fix`, and then it took about 3 month until I was notified that the validation has passed, but the pages are still under "Discovered - currently not indexed".

Here is an image from Google Search Console:

[image]

For information the validation passed at 19/11/2022, and this image is taken at 22/11/2022, and the pages are still not indexed, what should I do?

I also got this message from Google:

> Google has validated your fix of Page indexing issues on site
> example.com. The specific issue validated was 'Discovered -
> currently not indexed'.
>
> 9 pages on your site were validated as fixed.
>
> To examine full details on the validation progress and to learn if
> there are other Page indexing related issues to fix, please follow
> this link."

There should be 9 pages have fixed, but the problem is they are still not indexed.

Comment: There's really nothing we can do to help since this depends on your content and Google's crawling que and algorithm. Please review the questions marked as a duplicate and Google's help guide [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en).